# Is it possible to nest sentences in the same transaction?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, asynchronous, web-sql

I'm currently playing around with the asynchronous API of WebSql. Given this code:

```
        db.transaction(
            function (tx) {                      
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table",
                    [],
                    function(t, resultSet){ //Anonimous function implementing SQLStatementCallback
                        t.executeSql(...); //#1 
                    }
                ); 
            },
            function (err) {
                console.error("Error in transaction");                         
            },
            function(){
                console.log("Transaction complete"); //#2                  
            }   
        );
```

I could not find this in the spec. The third parameter in `executeSql` is a function inplementing [`SQLStatementCallback`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sqlstatementcallback) . The first parameter in this interface is another [`SQLTransaction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sqltransaction) (named t in my code). Would it be possible to use this transaction object to continue executing sentences? In particular:

1. Is `t` the same as `tx`?
2. Could I use `t` to execute another SQL sentence, and in this case is #1 guaranteed to run before #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, transaction object is same in `t` and `tx`.
2. Yes, It is grantee to run 1# before 2# since you have already listen onsuccess handler callback. I want to achieve ordering of the requests, i use `t`. Whenever I want to let then run in parallel I use `tx`. See the code in my [websql request executor](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/src/6b115d3b6f828b537c0b3d5cc9ec8b26c6013eb1/js/ydn/db/core/req/websql.js) implementation YDN-DB library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how the WebSQL API works.

Because of the asynchronous execution, this is the *only* way to execute multiple commands in one transaction.

Comment: Then how does the API know when I'm done with the transaction? For example, I could call `executeSql` again in the callback of #1, then in the callback of that second operation call `executeSql` again. In fact, I could do other operations in `executeSql` callbacks, like connecting to a WS, which will delay the sql components of the transaction. An I could even call `executeSql` multiple times in the "transaction" block, each one with its callbacks.

Comment: >> how does the API know when I'm done with the transaction? Transaction is committed when it is NOT actively used.